# Prioritize OR Pipe in Regex based on first match in the regex not in the source?

Tags: python, regex

If I do a regex with an `OR` pipe like `(A|B|C)`

https://regex101.com/r/gB1eP0/4

It always finds the first match in order in my source e.g.

- ABC=A
- BCA=B
- CBA=C

I am trying in fact to set it up so the order I put the options is the order it looks for. In other words in the example I have it would always look for 'A' first and if found stop searching and return `A`, if not it would search for `B` and if it didn't find that it would search for `C` and if found return `C`. Is there a way to prioritize it that way so in fact in the above example it would find `A` in each case?

Comment: Which language are you using? Javascript?

Comment: Maybe `(A|(B|C)(?!.*A))`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Seemed to be the inspiration for the accepted answer so gave you a vote-up kudo.

Comment: Votes on comments do not give points. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on @WiktorStribiżew's example:

`(A|(B|C(?!.*B))(?!.*A))`

basically, the negative lookahead is used, and then cascaded for all the Or pipes (using the parentheses).

1. Match A (A)
2. Match B if not followed by A (B)(?!.*A)
3. Match C if not followed by B or A (C)(?!.*B)(?!.*A)

https://regex101.com/r/zQ3pW0/1

Comment: I'll probably ask this as a separate question but since you posted the answer thought I'd reach out here: This is my actual `(A|B|C)`: https://regex101.com/r/bQ9fW7/20. I turned on 'g' to show all matches to confirm each namedgroup option returns the right values. When I construct it with the negative lookahead https://regex101.com/r/bQ9fW7/21 although it finds 'C' correctly the pattern is messed up somehow and I cannot figure out what is going on. Any insight appreciated, I'll try to make a new question out of it if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, discovered paragon and have been shut off from the real world for a bit :). I assume you found your answer already, but in case you haven't, the problem lies with the non-greedy quantifier you have there. Since it will match until the lookahead can pass, which is why it goes until the second '*' character. To fix it: https://regex101.com/r/kP7wM0/1.  Instead of using .*, i used [^*\\] (you can also add your new line character(s) if you want). Now, even when using the g option, only thing that should match is A. B/C can't match in there since the negative lookahead failed.